# How to perform Calculations on (excel) ListObject.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ListObject ("format as table") with about 10,000 rows. One of the columns (#9) is a dollar value.

I want to calculate the average of the dollar values that are visible after filters are applied. As the filter changes, I want the calculation to refresh.

NArrowing down the range - easy as:

```
Dim quotebook As ListObject
Set quotebook= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("quotebook").ListObjects("BookData")
With quotebook
    Debug.Print .DataBodyRange.Columns(9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    Debug.Print .DataBodyRange.Columns(9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
End With
```

OUTPUT

```
14 
$J$6780,$J$7224:$J$7236
```

But trying to do a calculation? I'm stumped

```
    Debug.Print Sum(.DataBodyRange.Columns(9))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Subtotal method of the Application object...

```
Debug.Print Application.Subtotal(9, .DataBodyRange.Columns(9))
```